# Reference comment count on different using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a BlogPage that references all my blogs with snippets of text. These can be clicked to view the full blog on a ViewBlog page, at the bottom of the view-blog page you can add a comment, and all comments are subsequently shown on this page.

I want to be able to reference the amount of comments made on every post some where on the snippet box on the blog page as screenshot below shows (I don't require help with the code for this, only the code to be able to reference it on the BlogPage;

[image]

**MODELS.PY**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    text = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True, default="text")
    featured_text = models.TextField(max_length=550, null=True, blank=True, default="text")
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="default.png")
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class BlogComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField('Name',max_length=100, default="")
    text = models.TextField('Comment',max_length=1000, default="")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
            ordering = ("date",) 

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s -- Name: %s'%(self.post.title, self.name)
```

**VIEWS**

```
def BlogPage(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-date')
    blog_paginator = Paginator(posts, per_page=4)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page = blog_paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {'page': page}
    

    return render(request, 'mhpapp/blog.html', context)

def ViewBlog(request, slug):
    
    try:
        blog = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
        print("Blog with this slug does not exist")
        blog = None

    comments = blog.comments.filter(status=True)

    user_comment = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            user_comment.post = blog
            user_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, 'mhpapp/view-blog.html', {'blog': blog, 'slug': slug, 'comments': user_comment, 'comments': comments, 'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the reverse relation from Comment to Blog like `blog.comments.all().count()` will return all comments related to a blog. You could probably use a method on your Blog model:

```
@property
def comment_count(self):
    return blog.comments.all().count()
```

And in your template you can then use this property to show the amount of comments.

Comment: None of these methods seem to work for me. I'm probably doing something wrong. I'm relatively new to django.